# how to use keyCode property in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to check if f5 button works in my asp.net  or not by using a script.My code does not check the if condition because an error appears and says that there is not definition of keyCode. I can write system.event but I do not have system.event.keyCode!!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
if (window.event.key){
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (window.event.keyCode == 116) {
                alert("f5 pressed");
            }
            else {
                alert("Window closed");
            }
        };
</script>
```

Comment: This code will most definitely cause a javascript-error for atleast two reasons. window.event will be null on this context and you are missing brackets from the first if (that is already in a wrong place). Also the question has nothing to do with asp.net but javascript, please use correct tags.

Comment: @Esko I use this code in my html head part in a asp.net web site!!!!!!!

Comment: @Esko If you know any code for reach to my target please write for me